# Django avoid user to go back to login page once logged in

Tags: django

The admin app in django has this behaviour, and I want to replicate it in my project.

In the admin, once you login and press the browser back button, shows the home page again, and the it does not let you go back any further.

It doesn't seem it uses javascript.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

My code

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('sinapsis-home'))
    else:
        ...# code processing the authentication 
        # the redirect
        return redirect(reverse('sinapsis-home'))
```

Comment: _It doesn't seem it uses javasccript._. Why do youi say that ?

Comment: @scharette because the home page does not have any in the source html code

Comment: yes it does. https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin

Comment: here is the link for js [code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js).

Comment: don't you want to show the authentication form when the user is logged in?

Comment: @scharette 
`yes it does. github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin`
That's the js used by the application (it appears once you use another part) but I repeat, _in the home page after login, the source html code does not have any._

Comment: @guillermochamorro what ?

Comment: I edited the comment

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I'm describing the behaviour of the admin app in django. I'm not making up anything.

Comment: @guillermochamorro once again, you are wrong. The Django admin index page is using Javascript. Why do you even say that it does not use some ?

Comment: @scharette and once again, I'm telling you in the source html code there is no one bit of javascript, unless it uses a redirection somewhere. Do you want that I post the html code?

Comment: @guillermochamorro you clearly don't understand how Django works behind the scene, but if you are so sure, then fine. I won't start a debate here. Sorry I could not help you.

Comment: @scharette Thanks for trying. But if you are going to be passive-agressive, better explain how an html page with no javascript executes javascript.

Comment: @scharette Hi! I posted the right answer after some time, I digged the code of the django admin and got to the right path. It was not javascript :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is partially the proposed answer, but adding a `cache decorator`.

**It is not javascript**, and it was so easy to prove just disabling javascript in the browser. I was slow on that point.

As you navigate the browser back and for, the *cached* page **does not load again**, that's why you can go back, in this case, to the login page even if you are logged in. I think this behaviour is prone to problems, for example a **csrf** error. I repeat, **not permitting the user go back to the login page once logged in is a standard behaviour of web apps**, including the django admin.

So the solution to this problem is adding to the login view a redirect if the user is logged in *and* a `never_cache` decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def login_user(request):
    ...
    if user.is_authenticated:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_redirect'))
    ...
```

Comment: There isn't any security problem with the login page being show, is just a page that have been cached

Answer (score 2):

Well, Like you said that isn't js, It's as simple as an if conditional like:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Return a login form to login
else:
    return redirect('success:page')
```

**Edit:**

After add your code, the problem was that you were using `request.user.is_autenticated()` with parentheses and it was deprecated in Django 1.10 [more information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#user-is-auth-anon-deprecation)

Comment: This is not the answer since this how I implement my login code.

Comment: @guillermochamorro can you post your view?

Comment: I just tested this on firefox. After I login to the admin panel, if I click and hold onto the back button to view recent history I see the login page. The only way you can overwrite the current page URL without adding it to the history is through javascript using `window.location.replace`.

Comment: @user2896976 not what happens in my case, using firefox and chromium, django 1.11.

Comment: @MauricioCortazar if I'm not wrong, this is the same logic as your answer
`def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sinapsis-home'))
    else:
        ... # process the authentication
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sinapsis-home'))`

Comment: `is_authenticate` is an attribute for Django 1.10 +, not a function anymore, delete the brackets, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#using-user-is-authenticated-and-user-is-anonymous-as-methods

Comment: @MauricioCortazar great thanks, I will change HttpResponseRedirect for redirect like in your example.

Comment: @guillermochamorro if worked for you, don't forget voteup and accept it

Comment: @MauricioCortazar sorry, but your code does not replicate the admin behaviour on this subject.

Comment: @MauricioCortazar It's been a long time but I found the solution, partially your own, I posted it as an answer.